# JNI error has occured

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I tried running this program as a test and I received the error, "A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again," followed by "A Java Exception has occurred". Any thoughts on how to fix this?

```
package java;

public class ExpressionsStatementsBlocks {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float num;
        num = 5/2;
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect there is something wrong with the JDK install.  Can you run other java programs? Upgrade to the latest JDK. Uninstall and reinstall if your already running the latest.

Comment: Yes I could run all of my programs yesterday, just today it stopped working. And I will try that, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use "java" as a package name. Try to use another name like "jaba".